# Kafka JDBC source connector bulk fetch cron increment by 1 hour every week

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am facing a strange behaviour in Kafka confluent JDBC connector using Bulk mode

How to reproduce:

Create a source connector and load it, for example at 6 pm

Create a sink connector with transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field or any system you prefer to log the writing time

Problem:

the connector for the first week will write lines at 6 pm, after 1 week it will start to write it at 7 pm, after 2 weeks 8 pm and so on

Example of JDBC Connector

```
    {
            "name": "sap-bulk",
            "config": {
                "name": "sap-bulk",
                "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector",
                "tasks.max": "10",
                "topic.prefix": "bulk_",
                "table.whitelist": "----"
                "connection.url": "jdbc:sap://----/",
                "connection.user": "-----",
                "connection.password": "----------",
                "retention.ms":"604800000",
                "mode":"bulk",
                "table.types":"VIEW",
                "poll.interval.ms":"86400000",
                "validate.non.null":"false",
            }
    }
```

Sink example

```
name=bgconnect-bulk
connector.class=com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.BigQuerySinkConnector
tasks.max=5

#topics=kcbq-quickstart
sanitizeTopics=true

autoCreateTables=true
autoUpdateSchemas=true

schemaRetriever=com.wepay.kafka.connect.bigquery.schemaregistry.schemaretriever.SchemaRegistrySchemaRetriever
schemaRegistryLocation=http://localhost:8081

#bufferSize=10000
#maxWriteSize=10000
tableWriteWait=900000

max.poll.records=1000000
########################################### Fill me in! ###########################################
project=--------
topics=-----
datasets=.*=mydata
keyfile=/opt/kafka/Gaccess.json
group.id=-----------

transforms=DropField,InsertField
transforms.DropField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ReplaceField$Value
transforms.DropField.blacklist=fieldtime
transforms.InsertField.timestamp.field=fieldtime
transforms.InsertField.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value
```

Any have faced the same issue?

Comment: Can you share your sink configuration too please.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i added an example of sink, but it happens to any sink connector type